# How can I set the cursor to the arrow-with-plus-sign on a winforms app?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, cursor

This is the cursor I want to use.  It has a little plus sign below the arrow:

[image: Arrow with plus sign.]

When I try to set the current cursor in my Windows Forms app, I do this (and it works):

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WhateverCursor;
```

The available cursors can be seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursors(v=vs.110).aspx).  Notably, I do not see one like I want.

**How can I get that little plus sign cursor?**

This is the list again, in case that link dies:

- AppStarting
- Arrow
- Cross
- Default
- Hand
- Help
- HSplit
- IBeam
- No
- NoMove2D
- NoMoveHoriz
- NoMoveVert
- PanEast
- PanNE
- PanNorth
- PanNW
- PanSE
- PanSouth
- PanSW
- PanWest
- SizeAll
- SizeNESW
- SizeNS
- SizeNWSE
- SizeWE
- UpArrow
- VSplit
- WaitCursor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system cursors only get you so far. For more you need to use an external resource..

You should create a proper cursor file `(somefile.cur)` and then assign it to the current cursor:

```
        Cursor myCursor = new Cursor(yourCursorfile);
        Cursor = myCursor;
```

To create it do use a nice application; I found Greenfish to work OK (although their own icon looks like crap ;-)

Make sure to avoid colors, as the above code won't work with colors, afaik.

[Here](http://www.file-upload.net/download-10858218/cursor-plus.cur.html) is an example I used in one of my projects..

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing!  It was my first foray into resources on .NET and with visual studio.  Resx files, embedded resources... I could really use a good article or book chapter about that!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it for a drag and drop operation (which is generally where this kind of cursor shows up) check out [DragDropEffects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dragdropeffects(v=vs.110).aspx), I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm actually not using it for a drag drop event!  Thanks for the pointer though.  I'll read through it and see if it helps anyways.

Comment: I think the reason that it's not available for use anytime other than a drag and drop operation is that it only makes sense to use it during a drag and drop.  Just my .02 for keeping your app in sync with the UI standards that Windows users will recognize.

Comment: That is definitely a concern.  It will be better than nothing for the prototype I have due in a few weeks.  After that I'll do a pretty thorough UX analysis.